# No route found for "GET /Index" when generating Symfony controller

Tags: php, symfony

I am using `generate:controller` to create a new controller in my Symfony 3 application. But the route is not getting found.

Here is the input/output of the command ...

```
First, you need to give the controller name you want to generate.
You must use the shortcut notation like AcmeBlogBundle:Post

Controller name: ApplicationSonataPageBundle:Page

Determine the format to use for the routing.

Routing format (php, xml, yml, annotation) [annotation]: yml

Determine the format to use for templating.

Template format (twig, php) [twig]:

Instead of starting with a blank controller, you can add some actions now. An action
is a PHP function or method that executes, for example, when a given route is matched.
Actions should be suffixed by Action.


New action name (press <return> to stop adding actions): IndexAction
Action route [/Index]:
Template name (optional) [ApplicationSonataPageBundle:Page:index.html.twig]:

New action name (press <return> to stop adding actions):


  Summary before generation


You are going to generate a "ApplicationSonataPageBundle:Page" controller
using the "yml" format for the routing and the "twig" format
for templating
Do you confirm generation [yes]?
```

... and here is the content of the new controller class:

```
namespace Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function IndexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('ApplicationSonataPageBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
            // ...
        ));
    }

}
```

... which is not called. I instead receive the following error in the browser:

> No route found for "GET /Index"

**Is there an additional step I need to do before seeing my action?**

What I have tried: I have so far tried every other type of routing (xml, php, yml) without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things to check:

Make sure your routes are included inside `config/routes.yml`

https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/routing.html
https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/routing.html#loading-routes
https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/routing/external_resources.html

Also make sure your bundle is loaded in the kernel: `app/AppKernel.php`

https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/page_creation.html#bundles-configuration

Another thing I notice, your action/route is capitalized. I'm not sure if this effects things but the common practice is `camelCasing` so you would have `indexAction` rather than `IndexAction`

There is also a command to show routes that are available I believe it is something like `php bin/console routes:debug` if you run `php bin/console` it should show you available commands

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth: I ended up just giving up and copying the following:

```
_index:
    path:     /Index
    defaults: { _controller: ApplicationSonataPageBundle:Page:Index }
```

... from the generated yml file into my app's main routing.yml file.

Comment: Yea, you need to make sure the main routing file includes your routes. There are many ways to include routes though. You included a single route. You should also be able to include Entire bundles and routing.yml files located in said bundles. But you need to make sure they are called inside the main routing file

Comment: I added another link to my answer, which shows the different ways to load the routes

Comment: Check out this link, https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/routing/external_resources.html that will show you how to include external .yml routing files